# How to access Vuex getters directly in data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Please see this minimum example:

```js
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: this.myText // this throws error, because I can't access computed here.
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["myText"])
  }
};
```

As you can see, the above code throws error, I can't access computed in `data` property yet.

I know I can access Vuex state directly, but how about getters? The value I want is within Vuex getters.

Is it possible to directly access Vuex getters?

Comment: Just do `this.$store.getters.myText` in the `data` section.

Comment: can you also show `getters: { myText  }`  function